# Is it recommended to use cstdio, cstring, cmath, etc. in C++?

Tags: c++

Is it recommended to use cstdio,cstring,cmath in c++?
I was writing a program that needed pow , strlen and sprintf ... for that the only way I could do it was to include these 3 headers. Is there a better C++ way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds to me like you're writing C, just using a C++ compiler. If you're using C++ I'd argue you should use the IO manipuation features of the standard library along with stringstream instead of sprintf, and use the C++ string class instead of C-style strings. You "needed" strlen() and sprintf() because you're dealing with C strings.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `std::stringstream` instead of `sprintf` and `std::string` instead of C-style strings.  But C++ just uses the C library for math functions.

C++ adds some convenient overloads for math functions (e.g. you can use exp() for float.)  They are available in <math.h> not only in <cmath> though.

Comment: There's a lot of useful stuff besides sprintf in string.h

Comment: But it's all for using char* strings. If you switch to C++'s string class you get it all in the string header. (O.K., sometimes you might need algorithm as well)
And it's preferred to use  C++'s string than a char* if possible.

Comment: string.h has some non-string functions too like memcpy and memset.

Comment: memcpy and memset are superceded by std::copy and std::fill. For POD types, the GNU implementation falls through to memcpy. Not sure about memset.

Answer (score 5):

That *is* the correct way.

Comment: Not sure I agree with this :) It sounds like he's dealing with C-style strings, not C++ strings. The question I would have is: should he not be using std::basic_string<T> instead of NULL terminated strings along with the IO manipulation features of C++ instead of sprintf? cheers :)

Answer (score 3):

For math functions, <cmath> is the correct way; however, for I/O, you should be using <iostream>, <sstream>, <fstream>, and friends. For string manipulation, <string> is the way to go.

Comment: iostream is much slower than scanf/printf (acm olympiads experience)

Comment: @osgx, not sure I buy that. scanf/printf have to deal with a lot more formatting than iostreams does. Which implementation did you use? Any reasonable implementation of iostream should be at least as fast.

Comment: on our olymp problem was with `sync_with_stdio`. libstdc++'s iostream from gcc has this enabled in Linux. After turning this off speed of iostream increased

Answer (score 1):

cmath isn't really superseded in C++, since there's really nothing to make them better. However, stringstreams/iostreams are far far superior to the cstring and cstdio lot.

If you have a C string, you can convert to a std::string quite easily, and the same for back again. If you're using strings, ALWAYS use the C++ string libraries over strlen, sprintf, and that.